# Top Bar icons are misbehaving - dropdowns aren't functioning, instead linking to Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

I just noticed strange behavior:

When I click the Hamburger **once** (and my mouse doesn't show strange behavior otherwise), I'm directly taken to [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/), i. e. the drop-down menu doesn't open.

It only opens on the main site and then I can go to another site. Usually, I will use the Hamburger menu to go to the specific meta page (I know that there are other possibilities), but when I'm on that other site and click the Hamburger, I'm back at StackExchange.

I tried stacks where I have an account on and one where I don't. Same behavior each time. The sites seem to work properly, apart from that.

Edit: Recent achievements and messages take me to my Network profile page (reputation tab and messages respectively).

Comment: Same when I click on the rep menu, the messages menu, etc. from PPCG.

Comment: The review button is also messed up, don't get a menu, it goes to the review page.

Comment: HAHAHA I noticed this this morning but assumed that I was just clicking too quickly... if you click before the page loads completely, that's actually old (somewhat expected) behavior.

Comment: A fix for this should be out soon.

Comment: JS console error `full.en.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'small' of undefined`

Comment: MSO link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366631/993547

Comment: It appears like `StackExchange.responsive && StackExchange.responsive.breakpointQueries.small.matches || (a[e] = o),` is broken in full.en.js. the breakpointQueries property doesn't exist.

Comment: @Nzall that is a real breakpoint then ...

Comment: I'm getting this too just to confirm it's not just this set of people ;D

Comment: @Catija: I'm really glad I'm not the only one who's fed up with that. (Or at least, not the only one that's been inconvenienced by that, I'm probably still the only one fed up about it.)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I tried to click on my notifications to see who responded to me and I was spirited away... despite being on this question still. My pages usually load quickly enough it doesn't affect me, though.

Comment: I'm afraid to leave this page now.

Comment: That's what tabs are for, @AnneDaunted :P

Comment: Inbox, achievements, and site switcher are all broken in an incognito window with scripts turned off, and after waiting a reasonable amount of time for page load.  (Also with scripts turned on and in a regular window, but in the interest of eliminating variables...)  When not logged in, if I click inbox or achievements I get a 404.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image: Joey from the show "Friends" saying "Very, VERY sorry"]

Comment: *Flags as NAA.*

Comment: Who messed up...?

Comment: @PatrickHofman That's a question where nobody wants to admit it was them...

Comment: Flagged as rude.

Comment: Flagged as Joey-Overflow.

Comment: Flagged as very, VERY abusive.

Comment: Will you add another gif, now that it's foxed?

Comment: While this meme may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of a substantial and correct answer here and provide the meme for humor. Meme-only answers are fun but do not really explain what is going on or what happened.

Comment: @RobertColumbia There was a bug. It was fixed.

Comment: @balpha It is pretty obviously a bug, and we can tell on our own whether or not it has been fixed. What would be helpful is knowing *why* the bug happened, *how* it was fixed, and what is being done to prevent this from happening in the future.